# minikube not starting once my laptop connects to a VPN

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

When I am not connected to the VPN, minikube is starting as expected:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> minikube start
* minikube v1.9.2 on Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise 10.0.18363 Build 18363
* Using the hyperv driver based on existing profile
* Starting control plane node m01 in cluster minikube
* Updating the running hyperv "minikube" VM ...
* Preparing Kubernetes v1.18.0 on Docker 19.03.8 ...
E0408 01:00:31.223159   17528 kubeadm.go:331] Overriding stale ClientConfig host https://192.168.137.249:8443 with https://172.17.118.34:8443
* Enabling addons: default-storageclass, storage-provisioner
* Done! kubectl is now configured to use "minikube"
```

Once I am connectong to the VPN antri triing to start the minikube, it fails with an error:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> minikube start
* minikube v1.9.2 on Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise 10.0.18363 Build 18363
* Using the hyperv driver based on existing profile
* Starting control plane node m01 in cluster minikube
* Updating the running hyperv "minikube" VM ...
! StartHost failed, but will try again: provision: IP not found
* Updating the running hyperv "minikube" VM ...
*
X Failed to start hyperv VM. "minikube start" may fix it.: provision: IP not found
*
* minikube is exiting due to an error. If the above message is not useful, open an issue:
  - https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/new/choose
```

Answer (score 2):

I was facing a similar issue while running the following command:

```
minikube start --vm-driver="hyperv" --hyperv-virtual-switch="minikube"
```

Then I went through some github and stackoverflow threads and was able to resolve my issue by running following command:

```
minikube delete

minikube start --vm-driver="hyperv"
```

In my case, passing 'hyperv-virtual-switch' argument was causing the issue.

I would suggest you to check if your virtual switch is configured with your vpn network or not.

If not, then you can perform the following steps to do so:

1. Go to network and sharing center settings of windows:

[image: network and sharing center]

2. Select your network and open the properties window for it. Go to the "Sharing" tab and allow your configured virtual switch over there.

[image: Network properties]